# How to bind a property of a POJO to the sum of the field of an inner ArrayList<ANOTHER_POJO>

Tags: java, arraylist, binding, pojo

hope someone can help me. I have to two POJOS, one for the Invoice Header and another one for the details

```
public class Invoice{
private SimpleStringProperty docNum;
private SimpleStringProperty customer;
private ArrayList<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetails;

public Invoice(String docNum, String customer) {
  this.docNum = new SimpleStringProperty(docNum);
  this.customer = new SimpleStringProperty(customer);
  this.invoiceDetails= new ArrayList<>();
}

/* Getters and setters*/
}
```

the second one is...

```
public class InvoiceDetails{
private SimpleStringProperty taxRate;
private SimpleDoubleProperty taxAmount;
private SimpleDoubleProperty amount;

public InvoiceDetails(String taxRate, Double taxAmount, Double amount) {
  this.taxRate= new SimpleStringProperty(taxRate);
  this.taxAmount= new SimpleDoubleProperty(taxAmount);
  this.amount= new SimpleDoubleProperty(amount);
}

/* Getters and setters*/
}
```

The question is how can I bind a field of the POJO `Invoices`, to the sum of the field `amount` of the POJO `InvoiceDetails`. Something like this:

```
public class Invoice{
private SimpleStringProperty docNum;
private SimpleStringProperty customer;
private ArrayList<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetails;
private SimpleDoubleProperty totalAmount;

public Invoice(String docNum, String customer) {
  this.docNum = new SimpleStringProperty(docNum);
  this.customer = new SimpleStringProperty(customer);
  this.invoiceDetails= new ArrayList<>();
  this.totalAmount.bind(....)
}

/* Getters and setters*/
}
```

Which would be the better way to achive this. Maybe collecting the data in a stream and binding  to the field totalAmount? 
Thanks in advance for you time.

Comment: `totalAmount` should be the sum of each `amount` of each `InvoiceDetail`?

Comment: Yeah, let's suposse one Invoice has an ArrayList of 3 InvoiceDetails with the value of amount; 1,2 and 3. The totalAmount in the _parent_ POJO `Invoice` should be 6.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just extend a List (the example shows ArrayList extension) and change the field on list members changes.

```
public class DemoList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DetailList list = new DetailList();
        Invoice i = new Invoice(list);

        System.out.println(i.getTotalAmount());

        list.add(new Details(42));
        list.add(new Details(42));
        System.out.println(i.getTotalAmount());
        list.remove(0);
        System.out.println(i.getTotalAmount());
    }

}

class Invoice {
    final DetailList details;

    public Invoice(DetailList details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public int getTotalAmount() {
        return details.getTotalAmount();
    }
}
class Details {
    final int amount;

    public Details(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
class DetailList extends ArrayList<Details> {
    int totalAmount=0;
    public DetailList() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Details t) {
        boolean res = super.add(t);
        recalculateTotal();
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, Details element) {
        super.add(index, element);
        recalculateTotal();
    }

    @Override
    public Details remove(int index) {
        Details res = super.remove(index);
        recalculateTotal();
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        boolean res = super.remove(o);
        recalculateTotal();
        return res;
    }

    private void recalculateTotal() {
        totalAmount=0;
        this.stream().forEach(item -> {
            totalAmount+=item.amount;
        });
    }
    public int getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice idea, but i wouldn't always call recalculate. when adding a new Detail, you can simply do `totalAmount+=item.amount` and when removing a element `totalAmount-=item.amount`. only case you should call recalculate is when you change the amount of a `Detail` (which should be possible (not final)). otherwise its only taking processing time where it is not needed

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I agree. It's easier to calculate diff. The example is simplified one. Amount should be final or we should add the same logic (notify about changes to recalculate total) to the Details class.

Comment: yeah if you change the amount you have to notify about it. i think there are some cases in which the amount should be possible to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your time. I finally found out another solution that I think is more simple.
I bind the `SimpleDoubleProperty totalAmount` to a `DoubleBinding`, and this one is the result of a stream through the `ArrayList<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetails`.

```
    public class Invoice{
    private SimpleStringProperty docNum;
    private SimpleStringProperty customer;
    private ArrayList<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetails;
    private SimpleDoubleProperty totalAmount;

    public Invoice(String docNum, String customer) {
       this.docNum = new SimpleStringProperty(docNum);
       this.customer = new SimpleStringProperty(customer);
       this.invoiceDetails= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /* Getters and setters */
     public SimpleDoubleProperty totalAmountProperty() {
          if (this.totalAmount == null) {
            this.totalAmount = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
           }
      DoubleBinding ta = new DoubleBinding() {
         @Override
         protected double computeValue() {
            Double result = detalleIvaList.stream()
             .mapToDouble(DetalleIva::getBaseImponible).reduce(0.0, Double::sum);
            return new BigDecimal(result).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
         }
      };
      this.totalAmount.bind(ta);
      return this.totalAmount;
    }

    public Double getTotalAmount() {
      return this.totalAmountProperty().get();
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(Double totalAmount) {
      this.totalAmountProperty().set(totalAmount);
    }
```

Thanks again for your time.
Regards